# How to define a unqiue contraint within the scope of a foreign key

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have an Account table and a Customer table. An account has many customers. The name of the customer is unique across the account it references.  Meaning, two customers belonging to the same account should have a unique name. How do I apply this constraint? following is the mysql table structure.

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample`.`Account` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `created_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample`.`Customer` (
 `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `account_fk_id_idx` (`account_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `account_fk_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
    REFERENCES `sample`.`Account` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

Comment: Define named account groups and use the group id in the customer table as one of foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
unique (account_id, name)
```

In the `Customer` table.